# How to access fields from an array of arrays in Java

Tags: java, arrays, class, arraylist

```
import java.util.*;

class Cube{
    int width;
    int height;

    public Cube(int width, int height){
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
    }

    public String toString(){
        String s = "[" + width + "," + height + "]";
        return s;
    }
}

class myClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LinkedList<Cube>[] myCubes;

        myCubes = new LinkedList[3];

        myCubes[0] = new LinkedList<Cube>();
        myCubes[1] = new LinkedList<Cube>();
        myCubes[2] = new LinkedList<Cube>();


        myCubes[0].add(new Cube(5,2));
        myCubes[0].add(new Cube(3,6));
        myCubes[1].add(new Cube(3,3));
        myCubes[1].add(new Cube(2,2));
        myCubes[2].add(new Cube(1,2));
        myCubes[2].add(new Cube(5,9));

    }
}
```

I understand that I have an array of arrays. However, I can't quite figure out how to access a single value from a Cube instance in the array.

I would appreciate it if you could help show how to access a single field.

For example, how could I individually access the value 6

```
myCubes[0].add(new Cube(3,6));
```

I know that with single instances, you use the dot operator such as

```
myCubes.width;
myCubes.height;
```

However, I  have no idea how to do access single fields from an array of array of instances.

I would truly appreciate your help.

Thank you

Comment: try this `myCubes[0].get(index).width`

Comment: I tried `myCubes[0].get(index).width` and it didn't work unfortunately. I have not tried `Cube cubeInstance = myCubes[0];` , my goal is to access a single field from an array of array, I am not sure what would that accomplish.

Comment: Nevermind, it worked! Thanks @Saravana

Comment: "*`LinkedList<Cube>[]` I understand that I have an array of arrays*" then you are wrong. You have array of linked lists. Anyway since you are using generics you should use list of list `List<List<Cube>>`, arrays and generics don't work well.

Answer (score 0):

As the others showed you already in the comments.

I tried it out by myself.
If it would be an array of arrays you could simply use

```
myCubes[0][1].height
```

But as the LinkedList is not an Array but an Linked List you need to use the get method of linked list to get your element from the list.

```
System.out.print(myCubes[0].get(1).height);
```

Answer (score 0):

> `LinkedList<Cube>[] myCubes` ... I understand that I have an array of arrays

No, this not array of arrays, this is *array of LinkedList*. To

- access list you need `myCubes[index]`
- but to access elements from list you need `*someList*.get(index)`.

If we combine those two we get something like `myCubes[0].get(1)` (just like you did with `myCubes[0].add(new Cube(3,6));` where you needed to use `add` method on a list to *put* Cube in it).

---

But generally we should avoid generic types and arrays. Arrays would like to guarantee that they hold only valid values, so they are checking at runtime type of elements which are placed in it to see if they match type of array. For instance while this code will compile:

```
String[] strArray = new String[10];
Object[] objArr = strArray;
objArr[0] = new Integer(1);
```

we will get at *runtime* `ArrayStoreException` because we attempted to place Integer into array which was supposed to hold only Strings (even if we did it via `Object[]` reference, type of array is still `String[]` because that is what we decided on at `new String[size]`).

But problem with generics is that they are [erased at runtime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html). Because of that it is possible to have code like

```
List<String> strList = new ArrayList<>();
Object o = strList;
List<Integer> intList = (List<Integer>) o;
intList.add(1);
System.out.println(strList);//this prints [1] !!!
```

So as you see generic types aren't really that safe (its safety exists mainly at compilation time) so arrays don't like them because they reduce their safety.
So instead of arrays you should use another List like `List<List<Cube>>`. This way compiler will not complain about mixing arrays and generic types (because there will be no more arrays - at least in our code). Your code using lists can look like:

```
List<List<Cube>> myCubes = new ArrayList<>();

myCubes.add(new LinkedList<>());
myCubes.add(new LinkedList<>());
myCubes.add(new LinkedList<>());

myCubes.get(0).add(new Cube(5,2));
myCubes.get(0).add(new Cube(3,6));
myCubes.get(1).add(new Cube(3,3));
myCubes.get(1).add(new Cube(2,2));
myCubes.get(2).add(new Cube(1,2));
myCubes.get(2).add(new Cube(5,9));

System.out.println(myCubes.get(0).get(1).width);
System.out.println(myCubes.get(0).get(1).height);
System.out.println(myCubes.get(0).get(1));
```